# Django Admin - Permissions Not Picking Up for Staff

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-authentication

I think I'm missing something here. I have one `django project` (django 1.6, ubuntu box) with several app's in it, and I want one user to manage one specific app. It should be straightforward: select the user, mark him/her as `is_staff` and add the app's permissions. But that's not working.

It's important to note that I'm using a custom `Authentication Middleware` to authenticate with our `SSO Server`. The authentication is working fine. The permissions are not.

In my `settings.py` I have:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
   #[...]
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'middlewares.sso.SsoMiddleware', # My Custom Auth Middleware
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
   #[...]
)
```

Anyway, my problem is:

1. When the user access the first time the application, he/she is added to the `User` table;
2. I go the `Admin Interface` and mark that user as `is_staff`. He is already marked as `is_active`.
3. The user now can get in the `Admin Interface`.
4. However, when I add permissions to him, he/she still gets "No permissions" message.
5. The only way that my user have access to the app is when I mark him as `super_user`, but of course he/she can see and change all apps, which is not what I aim for.

I have a feeling that my custom `Auth Middleware` is the culprid, but I'm not sure nor know how to fix it.

Any help will be immensely appreciated.

**Edit 1: process_request() code:**

The process_request() function on my sso.middleware:

```
def process_request(self, request):
    if not hasattr(request, 'user'):
        raise ImproperlyConfigured();
    if "BBSSOToken" not in request.COOKIES:
        return self.redireciona_login(request)
    else:
        token = request.COOKIES["BBSSOToken"] #check token on cookies
        if token is not None:
            sso_server = "http://address.to.my.sso.server/sso/identity/attributes"
            try:
                opener = urllib2.build_opener()
                resposta = opener.open("%s?subjectid=%s" % (sso_server, token)).read()
                matricula = self.get_atributo(resposta, "userdetails.attribute.name=uid").upper() #user id
                nome = self.get_atributo(resposta, "userdetails.attribute.name=nm-idgl").upper() #name                    

                user = authenticate(username=matricula)
                request.user = user
                login(request, user)
            except urllib2.HTTPError, err:
                if err.code == 401:
                    return self.redireciona_login(request) #redirects to sso login page
        else:
            raise

    return
else:
    return self.redireciona_login(request) #redirects to sso login page
```

Comment: What permissions did you give to the user?

Comment: Why do you have auth backend in middleware? Could you show your middleware class?

Comment: @elssar I can give him any permission. Even if I click to choose all permissions (with is_active and is_staff) marked. I does not works. The user can only act when is_admin.

Comment: Staff does not have all permissions, superuser does. For staff users you have to assign permissions or groups

Comment: @elssar That's what I just did. I assigned all permissions to the staff user, but with no avail. Still "No permissions" message.

Comment: @ilvar I have to constantly check if the sso token is valid, and if not, redirect to the sso login page. I've added the code to the question body.

Comment: `'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'` should not be in `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` ...it should be in `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` ...perhaps this is why no permissions for users are being recognised

Comment: @Anentropic Hooray! That was it! Make it an answer so I can mark it as correct!

Comment: @aldux cool... can haz bounty? :)

Comment: @Anentropic hahaha! Yes you can, but Stackoverflow is says: "You may award your bounty in 2 hours"... Waiting...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem was this:

`'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'` should not be in `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`

...it should be in `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` instead.

Since there was no appropriate auth backend in `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` no permissions for users were being recognised.

Comment: I have this configuration but still staff is not able to see anything and edit allocated items in admin. Any guesses ?